# How do I know which article to use before a noun specified by a relative clause?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

How can I explain the usage of the indefinite article in the following sentences?

> - Thanksgiving is a day when we celebrate the harvest.
> - New Year' Eve is a night when I have fun with my friends.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to talk about the characteristics of Thanksgiving (e.g., its role in celebrating the harvest), you use the indefinite article "a."  Thanksgiving is a particular day, perhaps among several, for harvest celebrations.

When you want to talk about the definition of Thanksgiving, use the definite article "the."  Thanksgiving is the day to celebrate the harvest, that's what it's for, and it's the only one.

Comment: Are these sentences correct 1. **February 14** is **the day** when people give cards to the ones they love. 2. **Valentine's Day** is **a day** when peolpe give cards to the ones they love.

Comment: They're both correct.  As I noted, they just say slightly different things.  For the unromantic,  February 14 is just a day, some day, any old day, when people waste money on meaningless messages to those they claim to love, but for lovers, Valentine's Day is the special day to express their depth of feeling for each other to each other.  (I  may have exaggerated a bit for effect.)

Comment: What about the use of *the* when I want to talk about a special Thanksgiving, e.g. the Thanksgiving in 2005, when aunt Elisabeth burned the turkey and we had to order something from a restaurant with delivery service. We had to wait 2 hours before we got our order. :-)

Comment: Your last sentence is not quite correct. Thanksgiving is still **a** day to celebrate the harvest. It might be the main day in the USA and/or some other countries, but there can be others like the German "Erntedankfest", although that has a religious background.

Comment: Why was that special?  Everyone knows that Aunt Elisabeth is hopeless in the kitchen.  You were just lucky to find a restaurant that would deliver on Thanksgiving.  That said, your use of the definite article before "Thanksgiving" is correct, but it's a different usage than the ones in the OP's examples.

Comment: @Daniel, the particular ("the") implies membership in the general ("a"), and my sentence isn't to illustrate the truth about the fourth Thursday in November in the US, but rather the implication of the usage of articles.

Comment: deleted due to your new comment

Comment: @deadrat Your last comment I totally agree with. Anyway even if Thanksgiving would be the same all over the world, using "the" you talk about a specific Thanksgiving and "a" if in general. So why should I use "the", when talking about the definition. Saying "Thanksgiving is defined as **a** day to celebrate the harvest and it was started by the Pilgrim Fathers." would be false regarding your statement. Why? Using "the" in this case would imply that all other days, to celebrate the harvest are "wrong".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24971/discussion-between-daniel-and-deadrat).

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether the object is unique or not.

> Thanksgiving is a day when we celebrate the harvest.

There may be several days when we celebrate the harvest; Thanksgiving is one of them.

> New Year' Eve is a night when I have fun with my friends.

There are several nights when you have fun with your friends (if not, you should get out more). New Years' Eve is one of them.

> Christmas is the day when Santa Claus brings presents for the children.

You wouldn't use *a* here, because there's only one day when he brings presents.